# Probability - Stanford Math Tournament

Tags: combinatorics

Nick has a terrible sleep schedule. He randomly picks a time between 4 AM and 6 AM to fall
asleep, and wakes up at a random time between 11 AM and 1 PM of the same day. What is the
probability that Nick gets between 6 and 7 hours of sleep?

Solution is posted here: https://www.stanfordmathtournament.com/pdfs/smt2013/advanced-solutions.pdf

The solution uses geometric reasoning.

Can someone verify if the Calculus method below is correct?

IF you analyse the timeline, if he sleeps between 4Am and 5 AM, his wake up time would be t+6 (10AM to 11AM) and t+7 would be ( 11AM to 12 Noon). Effectively, wake up interval would be anytime t that lies between 11AM and 12 Noon. Likewise if he sleeps at 5 am, his wake up time would be t+6 (11 am and 12 Noon) and t+7 would be (12Noon to 1AM). Effectively, wake up interval would be one full hour to get 6-7 hours of sleep.

probability of getting 6 to 7 hours of sleep by sleeping at x AM between 4AM and 5AM and waking up at y PM between (11AM and 12PM) $= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y} \frac{1}{4}dydx = \frac{1}{8}$

probability of getting 6 to 7 hours of sleep by sleeping at x AM between 5AM and 6AM and waking up at y PM between 12 Noon and 1 PM = $= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{4}dxdy= \frac{1}{4}$

Thus probability of getting 6 to 7 hours of sleep$=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4}= \frac{3}{8}$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I fail to see what this question has to do with combinatorics.

Comment: It is stirctly under the subject of Advanced Topics which mainly covers Combinatorics - May be i should change the title. To more like Probability. Apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the figure, where the blue area divided by the total area is the probability between 6 and 7 hours of sleep are had:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

We'll go back to when there were only *integers*

Bed time: $4$ AM to $6$ AM
Wake time: $11$ AM to $1$ PM

Sample space: $3 \times 3 = 9$
Outcomes that satisfy event: $(4, 11), (5, 11), (5, 12), (6, 12), (6, 1)$ i.e. $5$

Probability of $7$ hours sleep = $\frac{5}{9}$

How does/should this *discrete* answer compare to the *continuous* answer (using calculus)? The shaded area in **David G. Stork**'s answer, does it look five-ninth-ish?